# Android and Eclipse: I can't able to find my device LG-E720 from Run/Debug Configuration/Android Device

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb, device

As title, I can't able to find my phone device into Eclipse.
I activated on the my phone, either Application/Unknown Source and Application/Development/Debug USB.

But into Eclipse not appear any device phone, why?

Thanks'

Comment: Have you installed the [USB driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html)?

Comment: Yes USB driver, but maybe I have to install LG's driver usb
But where I can find it?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the cmd prompt, and then take it to the platform-tools. 
Then type the commands

```
    adb kill-server
```

and then

```
    adb start-server
```

Then to list the connected devices,

```
    adb devices
```

you will see the list of active devices including the emulator. If the device is not present, continue the steps for some time..

After you get the device listed among the active ones, you can run it in debug mode.

Think, this will help you..! :)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand...where i have go???? cmd prompt (DOS) and i have digit adb kill-server?

Comment: You can use task manager instead and just kill adb.exe. @DroidBee refers to the command line utility that can be found in sdk/tools. And yes you would open command prompt, cd to "tools" directory of you android installation and type commands above

Comment: Could you please tell me which is your OS? for windows, take "cmd" from start menu, and cd to "platform-tools". In there you type the following commands.. If its in linux, take "Konsole" , then cd to "platform-tools". Only thing is that you should use sudo commands in linux eg : "sudo ./adb kill-server", "./adb start-server" nad "./adb devices" Hope you got it this time.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on 2 of my phones (Nexus 1 and Amaze 4G). After some research I found that people try to overcome this by restarting Eclipse and ADB (only Eclipse won't do) but it took me rebooting the system and phone to make it work again. If you can go to Eclipse->Window->Open Perspective->DDMS and see if your phone shows there with red bug icon next to your app. If so then try what I described above. If you don't see your device in DDMS perspective then it's your USB driver that is not working and needs to be reinstalled

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with my LG P520. In my case, the problem was as a result of me setting the minimum Android level to Android 2.3(9) while the phone was a Froyo/Android 2.2(8) phone. Hence, it was not a compatible device and would hence not be shown in list of compatible devices.

Answer (score -1):

connect your PC with internet may be it will install some software to connect it with the phone debugger and make sure you enable the usb debugging on your phone.

Comment: What? Sorry but I don't understand

Comment: I'm asking about the driver installation for you LG phone which it will automatically get when connected to internet and if windows automatic update is on.